# Policy space optimization? Reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence

What are the reasons that you have an easier time choosing a Policy optimization algorithm when the state space is high dimensional, are there also any other reasons in the task's attributes for picking a Policy optimization algorithm?

Thanks